# Constructing objects based on enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have a class that builds objects based on an enum value. So several properties of these objects are based on some enum value, a type.

Option 1:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, ViewType) {
    VTHouse,
    VTCar,
    VTChair,
    ...
};
```

I have several methods that determine properties of the object based on the type.

```
- (NSURL*)urlForViewType:(ViewType)type {

    NSURL *url = nil;

    switch (type) {
        case VTHouse: {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"House url"];
            break;
        }
        case VTCar: {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Car url"];
            break;
        }
        case VTChair: {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Chair url"];
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

    return url;
}

- (NSURL*)isSelectableViewType:(ViewType)type {

    BOOL selectable = NO;

    switch (type) {
        case VTHouse: {
            selectable = YES;
            break;
        }
        case VTCar: {
            selectable = YES;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }

    return selectable;
}

- (NSURL*)colorForViewType:(ViewType)type {

    UIColor *color = nil;

    switch (type) {
        case VTHouse: {
            color = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        }
        case VTCar: {
            color = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;
        }
        case VTChair: {
            color = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

    return color;
}

// And so on...
```

Then I have a method that the user of this class would call.

```
- (SpecialView*)specialViewForType:(ViewType)type {

    NSURL *url = [self urlForViewType:type];
    BOOL selectable = [self isSelectableViewType:type];
    UIColor *color = [self colorForViewType:type];
    ...

    return [SpecialView specialViewURL:url selectable:selectable color:color ...];
}
```

This all works very well but it gives me an uneasy feeling. Something just doesn't feel right. Perhaps it's all of the switches. I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this.

Another option that gets rid of most of the switches is something like;

Option 2:

```
- (SpecialView*)specialViewForType:(ViewType)type {

    SpecialView *view = nil;

    switch (type) {
        case VTHouse: {
            view = [self specialViewHouse];
            break;
        }
        case VTCar: {
            view = [self specialViewCar];
            break;
        }
        case VTChair: {
            view = [self specialViewChair];
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    return view;
}
```

Where each of these methods already knows what properties to set for each type. But I prefer option 1.

So my question is; Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this kind of code?

Comment: You could replace switch case with dictionary and do simpler lookup. Certain switch case rules that produce the same result can be grouped too. Also if you have common protocol for views, you can implement color/selectable logic within each of subclasses to avoid switch-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switches are subclasses from the last millenium. The easiest way to do this, is to have (private?) subclasses. Create the instance from that subclass.

```
@implementation BaseClass
+ (instancetype)newBaseClassForType:(ViewType)viewType
{
  // Do a look-up to a array or a one-time switch to get the subclass
  Class appropiateSubclass = …;
  return [appropiateSubclass new];
}
```

Then, the subclasses can override the methods, i. e.:

```
@implementation HouswSubClass
- (BOOL)isSelectable { return YES; } // BTW: The return type was wrong
```

More important: Why do you have an enum?

Comment: I like and dislike the subclass idea. I have about 15 different types and possibly more in the future. So having a subclass just to have certain predetermined properties seems like it may be overkill, although well organized. I use an enum to simplify the interface for the view controller. So all it has to know is what type of view it wants. What would be better than an enum here?

Comment: Store the class, instead of a home made type. Keep in mind, that classes are objects in Objective-C. However, there is nothing wrong in having 15 subclasses. Likely they are private.